# Exception in ContinueWith in Akka.Net does not restart

Tags: akka.net

I have the following code in an AKKA.NET actor

```
        Receive<UploadFileFromDropboxMessage>(msg =>
        {
            var sender = Sender;
            var self = Self;
            UploadFromDropboxToBlobStorageAsync(msg.Path, msg.RelativeSourceRootDirectory).ContinueWith(o =>
            {
                if (o.Exception is null)
                {
                    sender.Tell(new UploadFileFromDropboxSuccessMessage(msg.Path), self);
                    sender.Tell(new ReadyForWorkMessage(), self);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw o.Exception;
                }
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).PipeTo(Self);
        });
```

When the exception is rethrown in the ContinueWith the actor does not get restarted. Why not?

Comment: Are you sure it is in fact executing synchronously on the same thread?  See https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4A_Z7c2F2nYJ:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=za

Comment: It might not. Will verify but still not sure how then to force it to throw and restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContinueWith` is being executed as a continuation `Task` outside of the actor. The exception is going to be thrown on whatever thread is executing that continuation and not within the actor's scope.

`await` the `UploadFromDropboxToBlobStorageAsync` inside the actor using the `ReceiveAsync<T>` handler if you want to handle that exception inside the actor itself.

Comment: Thanx Aaron, I have noticed that when I used the ReceiveAsync mechanism that I get timeouts and hence switched to the continuewith model. The task could potentially be running fairly long. Its basically downloading and uploading large files.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case instead of doing a throw inside the continuation - use a `PipeTo` to deliver the failure inside a `Status.Failure` message - and then handle that inside the actor. https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.Status.Failure.html

Comment: Thanx I'll give that ago. Great to work on AKKA after the training last week ;)